# How to pass data in a data class to a function

Tags: function, class, kotlin

I need to use a function to print data from a data class and having read some other answers on this site, but I am still unclear on how to do it. Help would be appreciated!

```
data class Chemical(
    val key: String,
    val name : String,
    val formula : String
)

fun printans(Chemical(q):: data class) {

    println("Key = $q.key,  Name = $q.name Formula = $q.formula")

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val cuso4 = Chemical("001", "Copper(II) sulphate", "CuSO4")
    val cacl2 = Chemical("002", "Calcium chloride", "CaCl2")

    printans(cuso4)
    printans(cacl2)
}
```

I have dozens of errors reported eg:

```
test.kt:9:22: error: expecting comma or ')'
fun printans(Chemical(q):: data class) {

test.kt:11:2: error: expecting member declaration
    println("Key = $q.key,  Name = $q.name Formula = $q.formula")

etc
```

Comment: `Chemical(q):: data class` isn't valid syntax

Comment: Reading the docs is always a good practice before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong and since `Chemical` is a data class, you don't even need to build the string yourself, it will already be built for you:

```
fun printans(c: Chemical) {
    println(it)
}
```

> Chemical(key=foo, name=bar, formula=baz)

So, you could even simplify to `println(c)`, and not use a dedicated function since it does not do anything more than `println` would do.

If this format is not what you want, I would recommend to override `toString` of `Chemical`.

```
data class Chemical(/* ... */) {
    fun toString(c: Chemical) = "Key = ${c.key},  Name = ${c.name} Formula = ${c.formula}"
}
```

This way, no matter where you pass it to `println`, the output will always be in your desired format, because `println` calls `toString` under the hood.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt and helpful answer!  I thought I had tried all possible combinations of the syntax but missed that one.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add braces and use `q: Chemical` instead `Chemical(q):: data class`.

```
fun printans(q: Chemical) {
    println("Key = ${q.key},  Name = ${q.name} Formula = ${q.formula}")
}
```

Comment: And fixing the function declaration to `fun printans(q: Chemical) {`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kotlin extended function feature!
Like so:

```
fun Chemical.printans(){
println("Key = ${this.key},  Name = ${this.name} Formula = ${this.formula}")
}
```

And just invoke it:

```
val chemical = Chemical("Key", "Name", "Formula")
chemical.printans()
```

You can read more on extended functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Comment: `printans` and `prinntln` seem to be mismatched.